# PHP Memcached get returning 0 always

Tags: php, memcached, libmemcached

I have `memcache` (installed on php5) and `memcached` (installed on php7.2 via libmemcached) both connecting to the same `memcached daemon/server`.

[`Memcache::get`](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.get.php) works perfectly fine and fetches the data as per my expectation. But when I do [`Memcached::get`](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.get.php), it always returns 0.

I have checked that I have compression off when using both extensions. I also tried toggling between `Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL` for `memcached` and it still produces same null result.

Interestingly, when I add a key/value pair using `memcached` extension and retrieve using the same key, I get proper/correct value that I added.

I am now clueless what could be the reason that it's not working for data already stored in memcached server.

**EDIT 1** : I did telnet to my memcached server, and checked that it actually has the value. Also, I checked the result code returned by `Memcached::getResultCode` is not any kind of failure.

**EDIT 2** : I may have narrowed it down further. I noticed that when I save `["key1" => "value1"]` from `memcache-php5` script, it stores and retrieves data correctly. But when I try to retrieve that same data with `memcached-php7.1` script, it returns 0.

After that I removed the data with key "key1" from memcached server using telnet. And then I saved `["key1" => "value1"]` using `memcached-php7.1` script and it can retrieve that data correctly. But when trying to retrieve it using `memcache-php5` script, it returns kind of the serialized data `"a:1:{s:4:\"key1\";s:6:\"value1\";}"` (this is json_encoded output)

So in order to upgrade, I may have to delete/flush everything and recreate entries in memcached server using memcached extension.

P.S. : I know the differences between both these php extensions. I have read all the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228958/memcached-get-function-always-returns-boolfalse) and it's not a duplicate of mine.

Comment: What OS you use?

Comment: ubuntu, does that matter?

Comment: Maybe, in windows I have many problems with it, but in linux it should work clear.

Comment: Well that's not the case with me, I will probably have to go with what Diogo suggested in his answer, which I was trying to avoid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already know, [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) are two different extensions. Even though, they're are used for the same purpose - connecting to a **memcache server** - each one of them serialize data differently.

That means you can't safely switch between them, without a proper cache flush in the server or independent server instances.

```
<?php
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcacheD = new Memcached;
$memcache->addServer($host);
$memcacheD->addServers($servers);

$checks = array(
    123,
    4542.32,
    'a string',
    true,
    array(123, 'string'),
    (object)array('key1' => 'value1'),
);
foreach ($checks as $i => $value) {
    print "Checking WRITE with Memcache\n";
    $key = 'cachetest' . $i;
    $memcache->set($key, $value);
    usleep(100);
    $val = $memcache->get($key);
    $valD = $memcacheD->get($key);
    if ($val !== $valD) {
        print "Not compatible!";
        var_dump(compact('val', 'valD'));
    }

    print "Checking WRITE with MemcacheD\n";
    $key = 'cachetest' . $i;
    $memcacheD->set($key, $value);
    usleep(100);
    $val = $memcache->get($key);
    $valD = $memcacheD->get($key);
    if ($val !== $valD) {
        print "Not compatible!";
        var_dump(compact('val', 'valD'));
    }
}
```